# SSRS 2008r2: Update report parameter prompt

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement to update multiple report parameter prompts on multiple servers. I know the parameters does not get updated by a deployment from BIDS. However I HAVE to update the parameter prompts on a large amount of reports and its not an option to manually edit each RDL deployed on the various servers. I also cannot find where this prompt is saved in the reporting database to be able to script these changes. Is there any way of doing this, has anyone ever done this in any way?

Any help will be appreciated.

E.g.:

> Current parameter name: **ParamShowWhichMovements** and prompt:
>   **showwhichmovements** Change parameter name: **ParamShowWhichMovements** and prompt: **Show movements into**

[As you can see the parameter name stays the same but the prompt changes]